# how to convert json string to yaml

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, yaml

I have the following code segment:

```
string stringXDoc = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ConnectedItemOperations.GetConnectedItemById(id).Edits.EditableData);
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringXDoc);
```

> this is the file that getting error : InvalidOperationException: Too
>   much recursion when traversing the object graph. There are 2000+
>   products.

```html
<product>
<code></code>
<ws_code></ws_code>
<barcode></barcode>
<supplier_code></supplier_code>
<name></name>
<cat1name></cat1name><cat1code></cat1code>
<cat2name></cat2name><cat2code></cat2code>
<cat3name></cat3name><cat3code></cat3code>
<category_path></category_path>
<stock></stock>
<price_list></price_list>
<price_list_campaign></price_list_campaign>
<price_special_vat_included></price_special_vat_included>
<price_special></price_special>
<price_special_rate></price_special_rate>
<price_credit_card></price_credit_card>
<currency></currency>
<vat></vat>
<brand></brand>
<model></model>
<desi></desi>
<width></width>
<height></height>
<deep></deep>
<weight></weight>
<detail></detail>
<images><img_item type_name=""></img_item><img_item type_name=""></img_item><img_item type_name=""></img_item><img_item type_name=""></img_item></images>
<subproducts>
<subproduct><VaryantGroupID></VaryantGroupID>
<code></code>
<ws_code></ws_code>
<type1></type1>
<type2></type2>
<barcode></barcode>
<stock></stock>
<desi></desi>
<price_list></price_list>
<price_special></price_special>
<supplier_code></supplier_code>
</subproduct><subproduct><VaryantGroupID></VaryantGroupID>
<code></code>
<ws_code></ws_code>
<type1></type1>
<type2></type2>
<barcode></barcode>
<stock></stock>
<desi></desi>
<price_list></price_list>
<price_special></price_special>
<supplier_code></supplier_code>
</subproduct><subproduct><VaryantGroupID></VaryantGroupID>
<code></code>
<ws_code></ws_code>
<type1></type1>
<type2></type2>
<barcode></barcode>
<stock></stock>
<desi></desi>
<price_list></price_list>
<price_special></price_special>
<supplier_code></supplier_code>
</subproduct><subproduct><VaryantGroupID></VaryantGroupID>
<code></code>
<ws_code></ws_code>
<type1></type1>
<type2></type2>
<barcode></barcode>
<stock></stock>
<desi></desi>
<price_list></price_list>
<price_special></price_special>
<supplier_code></supplier_code>
</subproduct></subproducts>
.
.
.
</product>
```

I want to convert json variable into `yaml`. stringXDoc is not same all time so that I cannot create class for `DeserializeObject<>` or can I ? Is there any way to convert this variable to `yaml` ?

Comment: Its a github repo may be it will help you https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet.Dynamic

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the YamlDotNet library. Here's a code example to convert youe object to YAML format:

```
var yourObject = ConnectedItemOperations.GetConnectedItemById(id).Edits.EditableData;
var serializer = new SerializerBuilder().Build();
var yamlString = serializer.Serialize(yourObject);
```

I tested this with following code:

```
class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Car[] Cars { get; set; }
}

class Car
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

var user = new User
{
    Name = "Me",
    Cars = new Car[]
    {
        new Car { Make = "Car1", Year = 2000 }, 
        new Car { Make = "Car2", Year = 2017 }
    }
};
var serializer = new SerializerBuilder().Build();
var asYaml = serializer.Serialize(user);
```

This produces following YAML string:

> Name: Me
>
> Cars:
>
> - Make: Car1
>
>   Year: 2000
> - Make: Car2
>
>   Year: 2017

Comment: OP dont have a object, he has string

Comment: @Eldho He does have an object, he is serializing it in his first line of code: `string stringXDoc = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(THE_OBJECT)`.

Comment: yeah your code worked well. but when I use 
throw that : InvalidOperationException: Too much recursion when traversing the object graph(my json string data is 10mb+)

Comment: @t.YILMAZ Could you provide a structure of what your data looks like? Also, can you split the object up in smaller parts? For example, get the first *x* number of items of `EditableData`.

Comment: @Abbas not sure if you get a notification when you're tagged in another answer, but FYI the OP has more information for you (in another answer, hopefully soon edited in to the question instead)